# How to Detect a Compressed File in C#

Tags: c#, file, search, compression

I'm trying to write a text search routine that scans a directory for a given wildcard file spec and scans the matches for a given search string. Everything works except for when I get to ZIP files. Here's the relevant code:

```
            string fileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            foreach (string s in lstSearchStrings.Items)
            {
                int cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, s);
                lstCounts.Items.Add(cnt.ToString());
            }
```

I know it only uses text-based routines so I probably need to change that. Any help in where to make changes / what to do would be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean it "doesn't work"?

Comment: It reads the file names in the zip files, but can't read the files themselves. Just looking for the proper way to open/read files in zip files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharpZipLib to read inside zip files.

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(@"test.zip"))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipFile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
    }
}
```

First you detect zip files using extension. Then read those using above method.

```
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(entry.name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found DotNetZip and am in the process of learning how to use it. The code you posted looks identical to what I'm looking at in the example I'm trying. How 'bout that!